# Калькулятор с помощью checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, калькулятор

Здравствуйте,есть задача реализовать следующий калькулятор на чекбоксах[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите при нажатии на чекбокс информация того блока в котором находится чекбокс должна дублироваться в форму слева,а внизу должна показываться итоговая сумма, я сумел пока что понять как можно реализовать итоговую сумму следующим кодом :

```js
var total = 0;

function test(item) {
  if (item.checked) {
    total += parseInt(item.value);
    $('.block h3').text()
  } else {
    total -= parseInt(item.value);
  }
  //alert(total);
  document.getElementById('Totalcost').innerHTML = total + " /-";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="10" onClick="test(this);" />10<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="20" onClick="test(this);" />20 <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="40" onClick="test(this);" />40 <br />
  <div class="block">
    <h3>Отвертка</h3><input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="60" onClick="test(this);" />60 <br /></div>
</div>
Total Amount : <span id="Totalcost"> </span>
<div class="price">

</div>
```

Но к сожалению никак не получается сдублировать инфу с того блока в форму,в котором находится чекбокс. Что подскажите? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Что-то не совсем понятно, в чем же у вас проблема.

Comment: как я понял проблема в записать "что выбрано" в какойто отдельный див, предположительно в тот что в разметке в самом низу

Comment: @ Rostyslav Kuzmovych все верно

Comment: @Cheg в данном случае  я хотел бы получить при клике на инпут в  блоке с классом block сам заголовок этого блока(Отвертка) и записать его в блок c классом price

Comment: Спасибо ребята за помощь вы все 3 сделали то что я хотел,  но Дмитрий постарался больше всех, все таки стили применил). Очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(() => {
  $('.channels-calc').each(function() {
    channelsCalc($(this));
  });
});

function channelsCalc( $container ) {
  let channelsList = [], period = 1;
  const $channels = $container.find('.items6'),
    $channelsCheckbox = $channels.find('.items6__item_checkbox'),
    $channelsLabel = $channels.find('.items6__item'),
    $total = $container.find('.calc'),
    $totalChannels = $total.find('.calc__items'),
    $periodRadio = $total.find('.calc__radio_input'),
    $totalSum = $total.find('.calc__total_price');

  for(let i = 0; i < $channelsLabel.length; i++) {
    $this = $channelsLabel.eq(i);

    channelsList[i] = {
      header: $this.find('.items6__item_header').text(),
      text: $this.find('.items6__item_text').text(),
      price: parseInt($this.find('.items6__item_price').text()),
      znak: $this.find('.items6__item_znak').text()
    }
  }

  viewChangedChannels();
  $channelsCheckbox.on('change', viewChangedChannels);
  $periodRadio.on('change', changePeriod);

  function changePeriod() {
    period = parseInt($(this).val());

    viewChangedChannels();
  }

  function viewChangedChannels() {
    let sum  = 0;

    $totalChannels.html('');

    for(let i = 0; i < $channelsCheckbox.length; i++) {
      if($channelsCheckbox.eq(i).prop('checked')) {
        sum += channelsList[i].price;
        $totalChannels.append('' +
          '<div class="calc__items_item">' +
            '<div class="calc__items_left">' +
              '<div class="calc__items_header">' + channelsList[i].header + '</div>' +
              '<div class="calc__items_text">' + channelsList[i].text + '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="calc__items_right">' +
              '<div class="calc__items_price">' + channelsList[i].price + '</div>' +
              '<div class="calc__items_znak">' + channelsList[i].znak + '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
          '</div>'
        );
      }
    }

    $totalSum.html(sum * period);

    return sum;
  }
}
```

```css
.calc {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 369px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f1f5f9;
  padding-top: 30px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative; }
  .calc__header {
    font-family: "OSB", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.375em;
    color: #333333;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 45px; }
  .calc__wrap {
    width: 84px;
    height: 12px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 125px; }
    .calc__wrap_logo {
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
  .calc__items {
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 15px; }
    .calc__items_item {
      width: 295px;
      text-align: right;
      margin: 17px auto 0;
      text-align: left;
      position: relative; }
    .calc__items_left {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle; }
    .calc__items_right {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0; }
    .calc__items_header {
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #0090ff; }
    .calc__items_text {
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #333333;
      margin-top: 3px;
      display: inline-block;
      border-bottom: 1px dashed #0b0574; }
    .calc__items_price {
      font-family: "OSB", sans-serif;
      font-size: 38px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      color: #0090ff;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle; }
    .calc__items_znak {
      font-family: "OSB", sans-serif;
      font-size: 11px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      color: #0090ff;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin-left: 3px;
      width: 22px;
      position: relative;
      text-transform: uppercase; }
      .calc__items_znak::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #b4dbfa;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
  .calc__radio {
    margin-top: 32px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 45px; }
    .calc__radio_item {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 6px;
      margin-left: 5px; }
    .calc__radio_input {
      display: none; }
      .calc__radio_input:checked + .calc__radio_box::before {
        opacity: 1; }
      .calc__radio_input:checked + .calc__radio_box + .calc__radio_text {
        color: #333333;
        font-family: "OSB", sans-serif; }
    .calc__radio_box {
      width: 17px;
      height: 17px;
      border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
      border-radius: 10em;
      position: relative; }
      .calc__radio_box::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        background-color: #0090ff;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
        border-radius: 10em;
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        transition: all 0.2s ease; }
    .calc__radio_text {
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #999999;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin-left: 12px; }
  .calc__total {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 38px;
    margin-left: 78px; }
    .calc__total_price {
      font-family: "OSB", sans-serif;
      font-size: 38px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      color: #333333;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle; }
    .calc__total_znak {
      font-family: "OSB", sans-serif;
      font-size: 11px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      color: #333333;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      position: relative;
      width: 23px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin-left: 4px; }
      .calc__total_znak::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #c0c3c6;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
  .calc__btn {
    width: 287px;
    height: 45px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #0090ff;
    display: block;
    font-family: "OSB", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 45px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 33px auto 0; }

.items6 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
  .items6__item {
    width: 361px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0 18px; }
    .items6__item::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #c1c1c1;
      width: 100%;
      height: 1px;
      left: 0;
      top: 0; }
    .items6__item::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #c1c1c1;
      width: 100%;
      height: 1px;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0; }
    .items6__item_checkbox {
      display: none; }
      .items6__item_checkbox:checked + .items6__item_true::before {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1); }
    .items6__item_true {
      width: 21px;
      height: 21px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
      background-color: #eef6fc;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin-left: 5px;
      cursor: pointer; }
      .items6__item_true::before {
        content: '';
        background-image: url(../img/sect5/true.png);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        position: absolute;
        width: 13px;
        height: 11px;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        transition: all 0.3s ease; }
    .items6__item_left {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin-left: 15px; }
    .items6__item_header {
      font-family: "OSB", sans-serif;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      color: #333333; }
    .items6__item_text {
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      color: #333333;
      display: inline-block;
      border-bottom: 1px dashed #0b0574; }
    .items6__item_right {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      right: 0; }
    .items6__item_price {
      font-family: "OSB", sans-serif;
      font-size: 38px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      color: #0090ff;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle; }
    .items6__item_znak {
      font-family: "OSB", sans-serif;
      font-size: 11px;
      line-height: 1.375em;
      color: #0090ff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      position: relative;
      width: 23px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin-left: 4px; }
      .items6__item_znak::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #bfe3ff;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs__box channels-calc">
  <div class="calc">
    <div class="calc__header">Каналы</div>
    <div class="calc__wrap">
      <img src="img/sect1/ntv.png" alt="Логотип" class="calc__wrap_logo">
    </div>

    <div class="calc__items">
      <!-- Здесь при клике на checkbox создавался пустой блок .calc__items_item -->
    </div>

    <div class="calc__radio">
      <label class="calc__radio_item">
        <input type="radio" name="month_2" class="calc__radio_input" value="1 месяц" checked>
        <div class="calc__radio_box"></div>
        <div class="calc__radio_text">1 месяц</div>
      </label>

      <label class="calc__radio_item">
        <input type="radio" name="month_2" class="calc__radio_input" value="2 месяц">
        <div class="calc__radio_box"></div>
        <div class="calc__radio_text">2 месяц</div>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="calc__total">
      <div class="calc__total_price"></div>
      <div class="calc__total_znak">руб мес</div>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="calc__btn">Подключить</a>
  </div>


  <!--      Блок с чекбоксами -->
  <div class="items6">
    <div class="items6__item">
      <label class="items6__item_check">
       <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox" value="149" checked>
       <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Базовый</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items6__item">
      <label class="items6__item_check">
       <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox">
       <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Базовый 2</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items6__item">
       <label class="items6__item_check">
       <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox">
       <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Спортивный</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items6__item">
       <label class="items6__item_check">
       <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox">
       <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Спортивный 2</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items6__item">
       <label class="items6__item_check">
       <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox">
       <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Спортивный 3</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items6__item">
       <label class="items6__item_check">
       <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox">
       <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Спортивный 4</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items6__item">
       <label class="items6__item_check">
       <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox">
       <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Спортивный 5</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items6__item">
       <label class="items6__item_check">
       <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox">
       <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Спортивный 6</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items6__item">
       <label class="items6__item_check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox">
        <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Спортивный 7</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items6__item">
       <label class="items6__item_check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox">
        <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Спортивный 8</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items6__item">
       <label class="items6__item_check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox">
        <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Спортивный 9</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items6__item">
       <label class="items6__item_check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox">
        <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Спортивный 10</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items6__item">
       <label class="items6__item_check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox">
        <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Спортивный 11</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items6__item">
       <label class="items6__item_check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox">
        <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Спортивный 12</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items6__item">
       <label class="items6__item_check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox">
        <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Спортивный 13</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="items6__item">
       <label class="items6__item_check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="items6__item_checkbox">
        <span class="items6__item_true"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="items6__item_left">
        <div class="items6__item_header">Спортивный 14</div>
        <div class="items6__item_text">190 каналов</div>
      </div>

      <div class="items6__item_right">
        <div class="items6__item_price">149</div>
        <div class="items6__item_znak">руб мес</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: как добавить кнопку сброса чтобы всё обнулялось?

Answer (score 4):

```js
var total = 0;


function test(item) {
  if (item.checked) {
    total += parseInt(item.value);
  } else {
    total -= parseInt(item.value);
  }
  $('#Totalcost').text(total + ' /-');

  $('.price').html(''); // очищаем список выбранных товаров
  $('.block').each(function() { // перебираем все .block
    if ($(this).find('input').is(':checked')) { // если чекбокс отмечен
      $('.price').append($(this).find('h3').text() + '<br />'); // добавляем текст из h3 в .price
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.block {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="block">
    <h3>Отвертка</h3><input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="60" onClick="test(this);" />60 <br />
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h3>Молоток</h3><input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="50" onClick="test(this);" />50 <br />
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h3>Шуруповерт</h3><input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="40" onClick="test(this);" />40 <br />
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h3>Стамеска</h3><input type="checkbox" name="channelcost" value="30" onClick="test(this);" />30 <br />
  </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<br /><br />Total Amount : <span id="Totalcost"> </span>
<div class="price">

</div>
```

Comment: .здравствуйте! Есть вопрос по данной теме, отпишитесь пожалуйста если вы здесь

Comment: @LiEm отписываюсь

Comment: Вот посмотритее пожалуйста данный файл буду невероятно благодарен, в знак благодарности сделаю ваш ответ правильным

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-WnINFpJa0aRE9RTXVvRXJDakk

Comment: @LiEm с такой задачей вам лучше задать новый вопрос, добавив в него этот код

Comment: Если я создам, то Вы мне поможете?

Comment: @LiEm если оформите воспроизводимый пример, то не только я вам помогу)

Comment: Если бы я знал только как можно реализовать воспроизводимый пример, весь интернет переискал и не нашел инфы

Comment: @LiEm, [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) достаточно подробно написано

Comment: @Cheg ваш ответ на мой взгляд лучший - краткость сестра таланта. (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_T спасибо. Вот только ТСы тут не всегда принимают ответы по их качеству.

Comment: @Cheg это погоня за внешними эффектами

Answer (score 1):

Примерный вариант реализации:

```js
var total = 0;

function calcItems(item) {
  var $leftBlock = $('.left');
  var val = $(item).val();
  var name = $(item).parent('label').text();
  var index = $(item).attr('data-index');

  if (item.checked) {
    total += parseInt(val);
    $leftBlock.append('<span data-index=' + index + '>' + name + '</span>');
  } else {
    total -= parseInt(val);
    $leftBlock.find('[data-index="' + index + '"]').remove();
  }

  $('#result b').text(total);

}
```

```css
#block>div {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 70px;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.left {
  background: #ded9d9;
}

.left span {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.right {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block">
  <div class="left"> </div>
  <div class="right">
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-index="1" name="channelcost" value="100" onclick="calcItems(this);" > <span>Опция №1</span> <b>100 руб</b></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-index="2" name="channelcost" value="200" onclick="calcItems(this);" > <span>Опция №2</span> <b>200 руб</b></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-index="3" name="channelcost" value="300" onclick="calcItems(this);" > <span>Опция №3</span> <b>300 руб</b></label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="result">
  Total Amount : <b>0</b> руб
</div>
```

Comment: B.здравствуйте! Есть вопрос по данной теме, отпишитесь пожалуйста если вы здесь